Azure Web App Service shuts down immediately
I just created my first Azure Web App Service and deployed it via Github actions. The status of my web app says running and when I go to the default domain url it says my web app is running and waiting for my content. In my log stream, it says "application started", and then immediately after that message it says "application is shutting down". I don't know why it would be shutting down immediately after starting.
I tried deploying and I expected the app to be up, but the content did not show up and in the logs it said it immediately shut down.


Hello. We'll need more details. Does it run OK locally? Can you share some code? Have you tried setting up logging (e.g. to Application Insights)?

@Joel Frase Can you share your repo?

Can you share the full error message show in log stream.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Here is a link to the repo: link. I thought I also posted a screenshot of the log stream, but I will add the screenshot if I have not already.

@AndrewB Yes my code does run okay locally.  I have not tried setting up logging to Application Insights. I have posted a link to the repo in another comment.

Have you tried just deploying it to Azure using Visual Studio's publish option, just to rule out the chance that your GitHub Actions Yaml is wrong?

I deployed your code to my web app. I was also getting same error:

To resolve this error I added dotnet SoundShowdownAPI.dll  in Configuration >> startup command and it worked for me.

Below is given .yml file for deployment:
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - webapp21aug

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'webapp21aug'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_xxxxxxxxxxxx }}


OUTPUT:
API is hosted on route /weatherforecast of the web app.
without the startup command:


with the startup command:
I added dotnet SoundShowdownAPI.dll  in Configuration >> startup command


